# Why does pointer artihmetic work with non-contiguous 2d arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, pointer-arithmetic

My understanding is that if one declares a 2d array locally as such: `int 2darr[x][y]`, it's not an array of pointers where each pointer points to a 1d array of its own, but instead it's a 1d array on which the processor does pointer arithmetic of the type `*(2darr + (row x nCols) + col)`.

In that case, the pointer arithmetic behind the syntactic sugar `2darr[row][col]` makes sense because our 2d array is actually under the hood just a single contiguous block of memory of size `nRows x nCols`.

However one way to dynamically allocate a 2d array is to first allocate an array of pointers of size `nRows`, and then for each of those pointers allocate an array of size `nCols` of whatever type we want. In that case our rows aren't necessarily stored contiguously in memory; each row could be stored at a completely different location in memory, with one of the pointers in our array of pointers pointing to its first element.

Given that, I don't understand how we can still access data in the 2d array by doing `2darr[row][col]`. Since our rows aren't guaranteed to be stored contiguously, pointer arithmetic of the type `*(2darr + (row x nCols) + col)` shouldn't be guaranteed to work at all.

Comment: the compiler will generate the correct access arithmetic depending on the declaration.  `int 2darr[x][y]` is not the same thing as `int (*2darr)[y]`.  various presentations on the equivalence between pointers and arrays has confused many people, so you're not the first person to be confused by this ;-). a contiguous block of memory is the more traditional and efficient way to represent an array.  an array of arrays is more flexible (e.g., it allows ragged arrays, where different rows can have different lengths).

Comment: You have hit one of the bizarre inconsistencies in C.

Comment: The answers seem quite complicated. I think it's better viewed as this: a `int x[10][20]` is one thing, and the array of pointers is `int ** y`. the subscript operator works differently on arrays and pointers, and I think that's a good enough explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why both an array defined with `SomeType A[M][N]` and an array implemented with a pointer to an array of pointers can be accessed as `A[i][j]` is due to how the subscript operator works, how pointer arithmetic works, and the automatic conversion of arrays to pointers.

A key difference is that, in `A[i][j]` with pointers, `A[i]` is a pointer whose value is fetched from memory and then used with `[j]`. In contrast, in `A[i][j]` with arrays, `A[i]` is an array whose value as a pointer is based on the array itself; the use of the array in an expression is converted to a pointer to its first element. Both `A[i]` for pointers and `A[i]` for arrays need to use a pointer for the next step, but the first is loaded from a pointer in memory and the second is calculated from where the array is stored in memory.

First, consider an array defined with:

```
SomeType A[M][N];
```

Given this, when the expression `A[i][j]` is evaluated, the evaluation proceeds:

- A is an array.
- In this circumstance<sup>1</sup>, the array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Let’s call this `p`. `A` is an array of `M` elements, each of which is an array of `N` elements of `SomeType`. So `p` is a pointer to the first array of `N` elements of `SomeType`.
- `p` replaces `A`, so the expression is now `p[i][j]`.
- The definition of subscript says that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*(E1+E2))`. (The formal definition has parentheses I have omitted for brevity.) When we apply this to the first subscript, `p[i][j]` becomes `(*(p+i)[j]`.
- Next, `p+i` is evaluated. Pointer arithmetic works in units of the pointed-to type. Since `p` points to arrays of `N` elements, `p+i` moves from the first array (with index 0) to the array with index `i`. Let’s call this `q`.
- Now we have `(*q)[j]`, where `q` points to element `i` of `A`. Note that this element `q` is pointing to is an array of `N` elements of `SomeType`.
- Since `q` points to an array, `*q` **is** the array.
- This array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Let’s call this `r`. `r` points the first element of the array `q` points to.
- Now we have `(r)[j]`, or, dropping the parentheses, `r[j]`, where `r` points to element 0 of the array that is element `i` of `A`.
- Again, the definition of subscript says this is identical to `(*(r+j))`.
- By pointer arithmetic `r+j` points to element `j` of the array.
- Since `r+j` points to element `j`, `*(r+j)` **is** element `j` of the array.
- Thus `A[i][j]` is element `j` of the array that is indexed by `i` in `A`.

Now consider a two-dimensional array implemented with a pointer-to-pointers, as with this code:

```
SomeType **A = malloc(M * sizeof *A);
for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++j)
    A[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *A[i]);
```

(We assume all `malloc` calls succeed. In production code, they should be tested.)

Given this, when the expression `A[i][j]` is evaluated, the evaluation proceeds:

- A is a pointer to a pointer to `SomeType`.
- By the definition of subscript, `A[i][j]` is identical to `(*(A+i))[j]`.
- By pointer arithmetic, `A+i` moves from where `A` points to `i` elements beyond it. In this case, `A` points to pointers (specifically pointers to SomeType), so the elements of pointer arithmetic are those pointers. So `A+i` points to `i` pointers beyond the first pointer. Let’s call this `q`.
- Now we have `(*q)[j]`, where `q` points to element `i` in the array of pointers we created.
- Since `q` points to a pointer, `*q` is that pointer. Let’s call this `r`. `r` points to the first element (of `SomeType`) that was allocated one of those `malloc` calls.
- Now we have `(r)[j]`, or, dropping the parentheses, `r[j]`, where `r` points to element `i` in the array of pointers.
- Again, the definition of subscript says this is identical to `(*(r+j))`.
- By pointer arithmetic `r+j` points to element `j` of the array whose first element `r` is pointing to.
- Since `r+j` points to element `j`, `*(r+j)` **is** element `j` of the array.
- Thus `A[i][j]` is element `j` of the array that is indexed by `i` in `A`.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> An expression that has type “array of *type*” is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array unless it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: (1) [6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, p3 - Draft n1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: Thank you for this great detailed answer; you were right in your comments, this is exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your array `2darr` is an array of *arrays*.

For example, a definition like

```
int aa[2][3];
```

is an array of two elements, each element being in turn an array of three `int` values.

In memory it looks something like this

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| aa[0][0] | aa[0][1] | aa[0][2] | aa[1][0] | aa[1][1] | aa[1][2] |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The part about pointer arithmetic that might have gotten you confused, is that for any array (or pointer!) `a` and index `i` the expression `a[i]` is equal to `*(a + i)`.

Using the above "formula" without array of arrays, what you get with `aa[i]` is another array. I.e. `*(aa + i)` is another array, that you in turn can use indexing on, like `(*(aa + i))[j]`. This second level of indexing can of course also be written using pointer arithmetic, as `*(*(aa + i) + j)`.

What you get with the expression you show, which without array `aa` would be `*(aa + i * 3 + j)`, is not correct when it comes to an array of arrays. I mean it will not be *semantically* correct. That is because `*(aa + i * 3 + j)` is really the same as `aa[i * 3 + j]` which in the case of `aa` is *an array*. The expression `aa[i * 3 + j]` (and therefore `*(aa + i * 3 + j)`) is of type `int[3]`. It's not a single `int` element.

Your expression, on the form `*(a + row * ncol + col)` is only correct if you have a single array. Like

```
int bb[6];  // 6 = 2 * 3
```

Now *this* array can be indexed using `*(bb + i * 3 + j)` (or `bb[i * 3 + j]`), and the result will be a single `int` value.

---

A "2-dimensional" array (which it really isn't ) implemented using pointers to pointers is also called a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), and it doesn't have to be contiguous. That means the `*(2darr + (row x nCols) + col)` expression is indeed invalid.

Again with a simple example:

```
int **pp;

pp = malloc(sizeof *pp * 2);  // Two elements in the "outer" array
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    pp[i] = malloc(sizeof **pp * 3);  // Three elements in the "inner" array
}
```

The code above creates a similar "two-dimensional" array as `aa` above. The big difference is its memory layout, which will be something like

```
+-------+-------+
| pp[0] | pp[1] |
+-------+-------+
 |       |
 |       v
 |       +----------+----------+----------+
 |       | pp[1][0] | pp[1][1] | pp[1][2] |
 |       +----------+----------+----------+
 v
 +----------+----------+----------+
 | pp[0][0] | pp[0][1] | pp[0][2] |
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

For the outer array, `pp[i]` is still equal to `*(pp + i)`, but while `aa[i]` results in an array of three `int` elements, `pp[i]` is a pointer to `int` (i.e. `int *`).

Since you can use array-indexing syntax with a pointer, the pointers from `pp[i]` can be indexed and you then have the "two-dimensional" syntax `pp[i][j]`.

While the `*(pp + i * 3 + j)` expression isn't valid, since the memory is not contiguous, all of the other pointer arithmetic shown above is. For example (as shown) `pp[i]` is equal to `*(pp + i)`. But since that is a pointer that can be indexed, `(*(pp + i))[j]` is also valid, and so is `*(*(pp + i) + j)`.

Comment: Thank you that's interesting, I thought 2d arrays declared as `aa[2][3]` were considered as a 1d array by the compiler so that the same pointer arithmetic as for 1d arrays applied

Comment: This answer discusses arrays of arrays. Although the OP has some misconceptions about how they work, the question asks how two-dimensional arrays constructed as a pointer to pointers work.

Comment: That is nice explanation. @jdigital what exactly doesn't sound right to you? I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: @EricPostpischil They *don't!* An array is an array, not a pointer (though an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element). And an array of array is *not* the same thing as a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @jdigital If `*(aa + i)` is an array, it can of course be indexed like one. And `aa[i][j]` is *also* equal to `*(aa[i] + j)`. And since `aa[i]` is equal to `*(aa + i)` then it follows that `aa[i][j]` is equal to `*(*(aa + i) + j)`. It's just simple substitution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: A two-dimensional mathematical array can be implemented with a C pointer to pointers. It does not need to be implemented with a C array. This is simply mixed terminology, mathematical and software, in the same discussion. The question asks about implementing a mathematical array using a pointer to pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It might be, but the OP (or perhaps the OP's professor) still have some misunderstandings that needs to be addressed, and to do that needs more than a comment. If you think this is a bad answer you're welcome to downvote it. It should still be useful for the OP I think.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: An answer can both explain misconceptions and answer the question. This answer does not answer the question. To improve it, you can add text that answers the question.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff Updated answer with more information.